# Python 3.8 Can't get os.chdir() to work with double backslash

Tags: python, macos, operating-system

I'm on a mac and my code uses os.chdir() but since I need to navigate to a folder with a space in its name, I have to use a backslash. I've tried to use double backslash and a raw string but neither have worked.
Here I've tried to do it with concatenation but that hasn't worked either. Any solutions?

```
os.chdir(whoami + "/Library/Application" + "\\"+ " Support/Google/Chrome/")
```

Also the whoami part is so that it navigates to the ~ directory.

Comment: "but since I need to navigate to a folder with a space in its name, I have to use a backslash" - you probably don't. Remove the backslashes.

Comment: You need to escape spaces in a shell command, but not here. There's no shell word splitting to suppress.

Comment: Also, if you think that `os.chdir()` will change your current directory after finishing python script - it will not work.

Comment: Ok, I tried os.chdir(whoami + "/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/") and I still got a No such file or directory error

Comment: Assign the `whoami + ...` to a string and print the string before you pass it to `os.chdir`.  The problem will probably become obvious.  And lose the backslashes, you don't need them.

Comment: Got it, it's all working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove backslashes you should not need to add them

Comment: Ok, I tried     os.chdir(whoami + "/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/") and I still got a No such file or directory error

Comment: Can you just use cd

Comment: @WilliamAnstey if this answer didn't solve your problem, why did you give it the check mark?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to elaborate, removing the backslashes worked, the error was caused by something else that is unrelated. Thank you for your help!